# Layer concatenation with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm planning to have the following design:

[image]

However my code doesn't seem working:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Concatenate
from keras import optimizers

trainX1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])   # fake training data
trainY1 = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])           # fake label

trainX2 = np.array([[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])
trainY2 = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

trainX3 = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
trainY3 = np.array([[1],[2]])

numFeatures = 2
trainXList = [trainX1, trainX2, trainX3]
trainYStack = np.vstack((trainY1,trainY2,trainY3))
inputList = []
modelList = []
for i,_ in enumerate(trainXList):
    tempInput= Input(shape = (numFeatures,))
    m = Dense(10, activation='tanh')(tempInput)
    inputList.append(tempInput)
    modelList.append(m)

mAll = Concatenate()(modelList)
out = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(mAll)
model = Model(inputs=inputList, outputs=out)

rmsp = optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.00001)
model.compile(optimizer=rmsp,loss='mse', dropout = 0.1)
model.fit(trainXList, trainYStack, epochs = 1, verbose=0)
```

The error message says that my input data sets are not having the same shape, but after I padded my training set to make number of samples = 4 for all 3 sets, I still get errors saying dimension is not right. May I know how I can design this network properly? Thanks!

---

p.s. Here is the error message before padding:

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Here is the error message after padding (happens on the last line of code):

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 4 input samples and 12 target samples.
```

Comment: Can you post the error message as is? It often tells what dimensions are causing the problem and what it expects while what you are giving.

Comment: Can you add the code  you used for padding?

Comment: Since I'm using fake data, I simply change trainingXList to [trainX1, trainX1, trainX1]. Same for the trainYStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input shape is wrong for the given input.
You assign the input a size of numFeatures, but actually you have 2-dimensional arrays and they are different (4,2)(3,2)(2,2). I am not sure about your problem, but number of samples and number of features seem to be reversed.

```
tempInput= Input(shape = (numFeatures,))
```

Furthermore your y is also weird. Usually you have X (number_of samples, num_features) and y with (number of samples, labels).

Use `model.summary()` to see how your network looks like.